# error whilst trying to deploy container image after introduction of private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

This command:

```
az container create 
    --resource-group MyRespourceGroup 
    --name AcrName 
    --image bla.azurecr.io/test3:latest 
    --cpu 1 
    --memory 1 
    --registry-login-server XXXX.azurecr.io 
    --registry-username XYZ 
    --registry-password XYZ 
    --dns-name-label test1234 
    --ports 80
```

used to work fine before IT introduced a private endpoint for the container registry to prevent exposing running images to the Internet (I just check this and created a registry without private endpoint and it worked). Now I get a pretty useless error message:

```
An error response is received from the docker registry 'AcrName'. Please retry later.
```

How can I further debug this or even deploy again? Maybe one can only create the private endpoint after deploying the ACI?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's using a private endpoint I'm guessing you are trying to access it from within a subnet that can reach that endpoint/on the private endpoint link, right? Edit: Just noticed your command - I thought you provided a sample from the Azure doc. Can you use xxxx.privatelink.azurecr.io as the name? and try from a machine that is in the subnet of the private endpoint?

Comment: my machine (a vm) from which I try to deploy the image using the stated command is in the same network.

Comment: Just updated my msg - can you try with xxx.privatelink.azurecr.io

Comment: @KedMardemootoo - thanks for your reply. I am sorry I do not follow. Which name do you want me to replace?

Comment: Ah sorry - so you need to use `xxxx.privatelink.azurecr.io` instead of `XXXX.azurecr.io`  for `--registry-login-server` Probably need to do the same for the image URL. Just realised I confused you with 'as the name' - sorry! :D

Comment: Thanks. Same error - sorry. The registry-login-server is taken from the UI so not sure why this should be changed?

Comment: So generally when you have a private endpoint on an Azure resource, it needs to be accessed via the privatelink fqdn instead of the public fqdn. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-private-link. We have private endpoints enabled for tons of resources and face this very often - although I'm not sure if yours is similar. What you can verify next is this: ping the privatelink/private endoint to see if it resolves to an IP on the same network. If resolves, check if ip is in the same subnet/any nsg blocking access in between.

Comment: If doesn't resolve, check if there's a private DNS zone called  privatelink.azurecr.io that has been created as part of enablement of the private endpoint. If you find that private DNS, check if it has been properly set with an A  record that points to the appropriate subnet, check if it is linked to the appropriate VNET, and check if link status shows completed

Comment: Sorry I think I might have misled you. I misunderstood and thought you were trying to access an existing ACR. Ignore what I wrote above - I will give it a try and see if it works on my end

Comment: @KedMardemootoo - thanks I managed to push a docker image to the ACR's repo but the issue is deploying the image to an ACI. I tried the above command and the UI. Both without success. Everything works for an ACR without private endpoint. So I think the culprit is the private endpoint somehow.

Comment: Currently, enabling the allow trusted services setting does not allow instances of other managed Azure services including App Service, Azure Container Instances, and Azure Security Center to access a network-restricted container registry.

Comment: Indeed it's the private endpoint and it seems it's not possible to do this, it's not supported. I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services 
Check the `note` and `important` sections

Comment: @KedMardemootoo so how do I prevent my ACI to be accessible from the Internet (i.e. outside my VN?). Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233333/discussion-between-ked-mardemootoo-and-cs0815).

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to replicate the issue on my end. This error shows up specifically when the private endpoint is enabled and when public access is disabled. You are trying to access the ACR over its public DNS name.

Private endpoint config:

[image]

Public access config:

[image]

For above setup, I get this:

`An error response is received from the docker registry 'kumbernetesreg.azurecr.io'. Please retry later.`

Then when public access is set to `All networks` I actually get a different error that's probably linked to the image I'm using:

`The image 'xxxx.privatelink.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest' in container group 'mycont' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.`

`The image 'xxxx.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest' in container group 'mycont' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.`

Creating the endpoint after creating the ACI could cause other issues later if the image needs to be pulled again from the ACR. You could check with IT on how to access the private endpoint using the private link DNS Zone `xxxx.privatelink.azurecr.io`.

Comment: Thanks  I will try to progress on this tomorrow. I was thinking this weekend, why do I actually secure the ACR. The reason can only be to secure the image repo? Should one not actually secure the ACI?

Comment: Yes indeed! It's to allow for private access to push/pull your ACR images instead of going through the internet. In your case, what you really want to secure is the ACI instead - which contains the actual service that needs to be completely private. Did more research on it and there's really no support for the scenario you have. I'll update my answer later. Also explored if making the ACI a trusted service would help but network-restricted ACRs do not support ACIs. This is all over the place in all az docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services