# secure ACI without private endpoint - docker image using plumber and R

Tags: r, azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry, plumber

I have a docker image, which uses Linux, R and plumber and works fine when pushed to an ACR and deployed to an ACI. The problem is, that the resulting endpoint is accessible via the Internet. It should only be accessible within our DMZ (?) virtual network (?) - apologies about my clumsy/potentially wrong use of terms. So IT created a private endpoint, which makes sense to me, but according to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html

See also previous related post:

[error whilst trying to deploy container image after introduction of private endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837906/error-whilst-trying-to-deploy-container-image-after-introduction-of-private-endp)

This is currently not supported for ACI? How else can the ACI endpoint be secured in my scenario please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your ACI in the VNet, then the ACI can only be accessible fron that VNet and it's not accessible from the Internet. See [deploy ACI in the VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet). But you need to know when the ACI is creating, the image need to be accessible from the Internet.

If you migrate your ACR with the service endpoint and it's only be accessible from the VNet, then ACI can't be created with pulling image from the ACR. See the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-private-link):

> Instances of Azure services including Azure DevOps Services, Web Apps,
> and Azure Container Instances are also unable to access a
> network-restricted container registry.

If your purpose is to make the ACI only be accessible from the VNet, make the image public or accessible from the Internet and delpy the ACI into the VNet.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry I am confused. Why would I want to make an image public, if it is a sensitive application? Does a public image not imply that someone can pull it? This does not make sense to me ...

Comment: @cs0815 The ACI needs to pull the image from the Internet. It does not mean your image needs to be a public image. For example, a private registry is also ok. But it must be accessible from the Internet.

Comment: apologies I am confused. I have a working docker image. I would like to deploy it as an ACI, which is only accessible via our VN. Maybe I do not need an ACR in the first place. Someone also mentioned that one can deploy as App Service? I do not really care as long as my restful endpoint is accessible via our VN and not the Internet. Any pointers very much welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @cs0815 Choose App Service or the ACI depends on your need. If you just want to have a quick test and run for the image, I recommend the ACI. If you need more features, such as the authentication with Azure AD, and so on. I recommend the App Service. Well, I have no ideas about your need. Choose yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But what are the steps to deploy an image to an ACI so that the resulting restful endpoint is not accessible from the Internet and only the VN? Having to place an image into an ACR that is publicly accessible (i.e. insecure) does not makes sense!

Comment: @cs0815 I give the link in the answer, deploy the ACI in the VNet. Just follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help but I do not think this constitutes an answer (not your fault!) as making the image public in the ACR is insecure. At least that's what I understand.

Comment: @cs0815 I don't agree. The ACR is a private registry and you can control the permissions with the [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles). At least, I think it's a secure way.

Comment: Ok sorry one last comment. Basically an ACR should not be assigned a private endpoint and other RBAC security mechanisms should be used.

Comment: @cs0815 You can try the RBAC with the ACR. And if this answer is helpful for you, please accept it.

Comment: I will have a look. The following looks relevant: https://zimmergren.net/top-10-best-practices-for-security-in-acr-azure-container-registry/