# ACI connection to private ACR

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

We need to set ACR to be available only to selected networks (not public access).

However, when we set this, ACI is not able to pull image from the ACR.

How to solve this?

EDIT:

ACI says:

```
Failed to pull image "<acrname>.azurecr.io/<imagae-name>:02b6d84d635c3d9ff4182ad1c50d16364695d3d5": rpc error: code Unknown desc Error response from daemon: Head "https://<acrname>.azurecr.io/v2/<image-name>/manifests/02b6d84d635c3d9ff4182ad1c50d16364695d3d5": denied: client with IP 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed access. Refer https://aka.ms/acr/firewall to grant access.
```

Comment: Please show how you are trying to perform, So that we can troubleshoot

Comment: Seems it doesn't support check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html

Comment: Well.. Did not solve the problem, but at least we know why it is not working. It would be really great if Microsoft thinks about the actual implementation a little bit more. This way a lot of the Azure components feel “unfinished”…

Comment: Sure i will raise a bug or feature request to Microsoft support team for this. Hope for the best..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found few relevent **[Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html)** and [**Document2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840156/secure-aci-without-private-endpoint-docker-image-using-plumber-and-r) which clearly stated that unfortunately we don't have this feature as of now to access the images from ACR through private network using ACI.

> Only an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster or Azure virtual machine can
> be used as a host to access a container registry using a service
> endpoint. Other Azure services including Azure Container Instances
> aren't supported

If your purpose is to make the ACI only be accessible from the VNet, make the image public or accessible from the Internet and delpy the ACI into the VNet.
But it doesn't mean your ACR will be public or your image need to be public image. You can have your private ACR and image but the images  will access from the internet not from Selected Networks.

Comment: Thank you. The last sentence quite surprised me. Could you elaborate a little bit more, please? What do you mean exactly by “the images will access from the internet”? Thank you very much

Comment: Image will access from internet means you will only able to access if you using public network(internet) not private or selected network, because once you try to access from selected network it will throw error. For more clear understanding about this please refer this documet2.

Comment: I updated the original question. ACI says that some machine with some IP is not able to connect to ACR. Is there any way to get this IP address so I can add it to ACR allowed list? (Any normal way, not manually reading container logs)

Comment: are you access from public network or private network?

Comment: I don't think we have this feature to allow specific ip of ACI's to add in ACR to access that

Comment: ACI is in private virtual network.

Comment: Not possible as clear stated in the documents which i have given